# .net core cannot accept multiple IFormFile in api

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

I have this code to take in a list of files but my api is not getting the files and I am getting a count of 0

```
[HttpPost("TrainPersonGroup")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> TrainPersonGroup(List<IFormFile> files, string personGroupName)
        {
            try
            {
                // create person group Id
                string personGroupId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                sourcePersonGroup = personGroupId;
                await faceClient.PersonGroup.CreateAsync(personGroupId, personGroupId, recognitionModel: RECOGNITION_MODEL2);
                List<PersistedFace> faces = new List<PersistedFace>();
                // Limit TPS
                await Task.Delay(250);
                Person person = await faceClient.PersonGroupPerson.CreateAsync(personGroupId, personGroupId, personGroupName);

                foreach (var personGroup in files)
                {
                    // limit TPS
                    //await Task.Delay(250);

                    using (Stream imageFileStream = personGroup.OpenReadStream())
                    {
                        PersistedFace face = await faceClient.PersonGroupPerson.AddFaceFromStreamAsync(personGroupId, person.PersonId, imageFileStream);
                        faces.Add(face);
                    }

                    // (personGroupId, person.PersonId, $"{url}{similarImage}", similarImage);
                }
                //await faceClient.PersonGroup.CreateAsync()
                return Ok(faces);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex);
            }
        }
```

But when I call the api with the multiple files, I am getting nothing. Would anyone be able to help me understand why?

If I change it from a list to a single file, it works. So I don't know what I need to do to get it to work for a list of files.

Comment: How are you POSTing the files/data to this endpoint? If I construct a striped down version of this method, and POST using Postman, it works (files param has my two sample files).  Are you sure your multiple files are uploaded using the "files" field name?

Comment: Never mind, I guess this was a swagger issue. I was using swagger to post the files and it was never posting correctly. The moment I used postman instead, it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Swagger to upload the files and it appears that swagger is doing it wrong. When I used postman and added the files that way, the API was working as expected